# CSS - Cover Image Gradient Over

Tags: html, css, background-image, cover

I'm working to have a gradient layer over a cover image. I don't understand why its happening in this way.

Have a look on the below code.

Source: [Wallpaper](http://www.wallpaperlatest.com/)

For instance:

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-image: url('http://wallpaperlatest.com/wp-content/uploads/latest-wallpapers-in-full-hd-definition.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 100px 0;
  font: 44px "Arial";
  text-align: center;
}

header h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header Content | Source: http://wallpaperlatest.com</h1>
</header>

<section>
  <h1>Section Content | Source: http://wallpaperlatest.com/</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't see a gradient anywhere in your code. What are you referring to when you say "I dont understand why its happening in this way"?

Comment: You need to elaborate on what you're expecting and what is going wrong. Are you sure gradient is the right word you're looking for?

Comment: Oh, just give a moment to edit my code. I hade a problem with inserting code it showed me lot many mistakes ex: to enter CTRL+K . I just edited some lines, i must have backspaced there. I'm  sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0, 47, 75, .8), rgba(220, 66, 37, .8)), url('http://wallpaperlatest.com/wp-content/uploads/latest-wallpapers-in-full-hd-definition.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 100px 0;
  font: 44px "Arial";
  text-align: center;
}

header h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header Content | Source: http://wallpaperlatest.com</h1>
</header>

<section>
  <h1>Section Content | Source: http://wallpaperlatest.com/</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for understanding and answering :)

Comment: I just did @Chandra Kumar since my account is new its not going to be public is says...!! But i will follow you.